# How to make cascade version set in maven?

Tags: java, maven, cascade

I have multimodule maven project and want to automate part of release preparing. Before release I increase the version of changed module A, and because I have module B depends on A, I also need to increase version of B. I know that there is "versions" and "release" maven plugins, but they doesn't cascade the update of version . Is it possible to make update of B version automaticly too?

Some additions to make it clear:
We don't use version of parent module, so i don't need to update it.

Before version bump:

```
parent module (1.0)
|  
|-- A module (0.01.00)
|-- B module (0.02.00)
```

After version bump:

```
parent module (1.0)
|  
|-- A module (0.01.01)
|-- B module (0.02.01)
```

Comment: It's hard to picture what you're asking - are modules A and B part of the multi-module structure?

Comment: Do modules A and B have the same version as the parent, and subsequently each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`release` plugin have `update-versions` goal and [autoVersionSubmodules](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/update-versions-mojo.html#autoVersionSubmodules) option that sets submodules versions to parent project version.

Usage example [here](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/update-versions.html).

Now, if you have dependencies between your submodules (`Module B` depends on `Module A`), they won't be updated by `release` plugin.

To work this out you can use `${project.version}` when defining dependency to `Module A` in `Module B`'s `pom.xml`.

For example (in `Module B`'s `pom.xml`):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>module-a</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

(this will work because both `Module A` and `Module B` versions are the same and derived from parent project version)

Comment: thanks for you answer, i've added some details to my question. I don't use parent version, so i just don't update it and it always "1.0". Module A and Module B have different versions, becouse B depends on A, but A doesn't depend on B, so i increase version of B without increase version of A.